# How can implement Feed Dialog from Facebook in Android Application?

Tags: android, facebook

[image]Implementation of Feed Dialog for 'Publish Story' in my Android App is not working. I downloaded the sample Facebook Android-sdk from the following link :

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/README.md#dialogs

In case of simple wallPost, my AppId is working.. but when I am using this for 'Publish Story' Feed dialog, I am getting this message after Log In: 
An error occurred with RomeFoodieGuide. Please try again later.

Even in web browser, I am getting the same Error message. Is there any work to do to AppId in my App..?

In web browser I am using the link as follows :
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=118611694896804&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response/

In my App, I using the following link :
"https://m.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=123050457758183&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response/&display=touch"

Answer (score 6):

```
    facebook=your facebbook object;
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("description", "description about link");
    parameters.putString("picture","link of picture your want add with share post.");
    parameters.putString("link", "Link you want to share");
    parameters.putString("name","Name of link");
    parameters.putString("caption","describe your caption text");


    facebook.dialog(context,"feed",parameters,new DialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError arg0) {
        //Display your message for facebook error   

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError arg0) {
        //Display your message for error    

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle arg0) {
        //Display your message on share scuccessful

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        //Display your message on dialog cancel

        }
    });
```

Comment: i had local image how can i conervt url to post like this

Comment: @Prasad hi, we can add local image to share in feed dialog, we need add photo on facebook

Answer (score 3):

I'm also working on that sample fb example, we have to do some thing on that sample code on `mFacebook.dialog(Main.this, "feed", new SampleDialogListener());`  by using [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/dialog/) hope it helps you..  one more thing I have tried [this](http://code.google.com/r/hrl5000-production-clone/source/browse/sample/src/com/codecarpet/fbconnect/sample/MainActivity.java?r=c5a8125f588b972d9c6e57f76925e0206f727a68) old fb implementation  code does't worked for me (may be it's for earlier fb ver)

Comment: http://www.integratingstuff.com/2010/10/14/integrating-facebook-into-an-android-application/

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to explicitly provide the feed dialog URL. You can use the SDK to display dialog. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/ for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Vikas... but this SDK is working only for posting something to your wall as in text matter. I need to share my application to facebook wall. In that case, image of application, application name, description of application and a user defined comment should be there.

Comment: I just added a snapshot of the example, that i need. captured image is of iOS SDK. I need same thing in Android. Is any SDK is available for the same in Android.